# Magento 2 - 404 error after changing "Custom Admin URL" from Admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, url

I changed the base admin url using the admin panel and now I cannot access the admin panel anymore.

I dont have access to the PHP file, I'm an online user, is there a way to find the new admin login URL?
The old URL was https://row.mysite.com/en/admin/
and I changed it to https://row.mysite.com/en/myname/

Now both URLs are giving a 404 error on my site.

I used this guide https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/advanced/admin.html?lang=en

In the textbox for the custom url, I pasted the entire url from above. Does anyone have an idea where did the admin login page go?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the "Custom Admin URL" is to define a "new Base URL" to use when navigating through the Admin. For example "https://admin.domain.com/".

But there is still an "Admin Path", which can be changed in the field "Custom Admin Path".

In your case, it looks like you only changed the URL.
You might try to access the following URL (**Custom Admin URL** + old **Admin Path**) :

> https://row.mysite.com/en/myname/admin

If it doesn't work, you can recover access to your admin by telling to the Magento configuration to stop using the Custom Admin URL:

---

With an **SSH Access** :

1. Log in to the Magento server and move to your Magento directory.
2. Execute the following command : `bin/magento config:set admin/url/use_custom 0`
3. Clear the config cache : `bin/magento cache:clear config`

This should allow you to access to your Admin.

---

If you do not have a SSH Access, but have a **Database Access** :

Execute the following query :

```sql
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE (path = 'admin/url/use_custom');
```

Unfortunately, here you cannot clear the Magento cache from the database, and you don't have access to the Admin or through SSH to clear the cache, so you would have to wait for a natural cache refresh (which occurs every day by default if I remember well).

---

**If you don't have any of those accesses**, contact your website administrator or the person who have access to the server.